# Who's responsible for property damage?

Tags: real-estate, property, damages

Hypothetically if there was a leak during apartment renovations on floor B which damaged the apartment on floor A below, the contractor blames the building and the building blames the contractor.

Is the owner of an apartment on floor B responsible for paying the owner of the apartment on floor A? Or is this between the contractor and the apartment owner?

Comment: This question is likely to attract close votes in its current form - it's about a specific situation, and it' going to be difficult to answer without appearing to give legal advice, which we don't do here. Would you be able to rewrite it as a generic question about liability between upper floor tenant / lower floor tenant / contractor / building owner?

Comment: Ok thanks edited to be made more generic

Comment: This question can't be answered without specific details, and those details would make it specific legal advice.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know without a detailed factual investigation by experts regarding what happened. Both are possible. It is also possible that more than one person has legal responsibility.

Making an insurance claim may be the sensible first step for the occupants of the apartment below.